# Where to store images during Django deployment?

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean

I've deployed my django project onto my Digital Ocean server. However I'm not sure how to deal with image assets in my html, and also image assets generated from users. So an example of assets in my html would be for example, the logo of my website. An example of user-generated images would be the user uploaded a post with an image. In development I could just get my html images from `static/image/image.png` however this method doesn't seem viable in production. For user-generated images it would go in `media`.

How do these 2 differ when going into production? For static images in my HTML the storage would be quite low so could this just live on the server? However I don't think it's possible to have images in a git repo.

Comment: Deployment tool like `nginx` has option to point towards to `static` and `media` directory.

Comment: Yes I am running Nginx. So I should use Nginx to serve the static images in my HTML, and then use an external storage (such as S3) instead of my `media` directory to store user-generated images?

Comment: Your server has enough space right, Then why you going for an external storage. Anyway if you are using an external storage you have to specify the public path of the file in html codes.

Comment: @RahulKP the OP may have some intention to going for external storage. that's not questionable .

Comment: @VikasDamodar Not questioning i just wonder why he going like that.

Comment: I can definitely store in Nginx however I'm just thinking to prepare for long-term scenarios where I will need more storage

Comment: You can use django-storages and boto libraries for serve media and static files from s3 to your website. both library give you feature to upload file on s3 and serve from s3 to your website

Comment: This may help you, https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/

Answer (score 0):

Go through [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) you will find your solution, it is a well-documented Setup procedure made by digitalocean.